# transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug takes a lot of time

Tags: android, build, android-build

Since upgrading to Android Studio 3.0, and now to 3.0.1, transformClassesWithDexForDebug has now become transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug.

The problem I encounter is that it takes a lot of time to build, on Windows especially. I have a friend who uses a Mac and the build takes like 3 seconds, on windows it takes 20-25 seconds. This was not the case before upgrading to 3.0.

Does anyone know why this happens or a solution to this problem ? Thank you

Comment: You can try use D8 (add `android.enableD8=true` in `gradle.properties` file) and check if is faster.

Comment: @PiotrAleksanderChmielowski I investigate you answer, but the result is the same. No difference, if not it's a little bit slower than usual.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this **./gradlew --stop** to stop the gradle daemon. And then start a new gradle building task. This works for me. I hope it would be helpful to you as well.